# Consistent Normal Orientation of Pointcloud in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, point-clouds, normals

Lets say I have the parametrization of an (orientable) surface in a symbolic way. I produce a pointcloud matrix from it and call it `mat` . I compute the normals to the pointcloud in the following way (in MATLAB)

```
ptCloud = pointCloud(mat);
normals = pcnormals(ptCloud);
```

The result will be in the following form (from two different camera angles of the same point cloud):

[image]
[image]

However I wish the normals orientations to be consistent (mathematically speaking, be in accordance to a chosen orientation of the surface in the sense of direction). In another word I wish them to look like this (the images below are produced using open3d from Python):

[image]

[image]

Due to some reasons I wish to use only MATLAB to produce the normals with consistent orientation. I searched a lot on net but couldn't find any command or function that would do this for me within MATLAB environment. I would appreciate a lot if you have any idea on how to do it within MATLAB.

Comment: There will not be any command or function for this to do it for you. You will need to find some algorithm to get it done.  There are various ways to solve this issue. 1) compute the normals well. You are likely just not using some robust method to do so, so "fixing" them later may not be the best solution, rather finding good ones to start with. 2) Fixing them later. This can be done, but you need to "mathematically" define what "consistent" means. That is a human word, and we can not code human things in algorithms

Comment: @AnderBiguri I believe that mathematically "consistent orientation for a pointcloud" means this: choose a point. Choose the normal at that point and consider it to be the orientation of the surface at that point. Then locally check if the angle that the "neighboring" normals make with your initially chosen normal is bigger or less than Pi/2. If bigger then choose the other direction, if not let it be. "somehow expanding" this "local" behavior to the whole surface would allow you to make a consistent orientation (assuming that the surface that the pointcloud belongs to is orientable).

Comment: @AnderBiguri However, I wish to know if already such function exists in the MATLAB community. I don't wanna code it from scratch myself.

Comment: If you can find it here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/point-cloud-processing.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav then good, otherwise, it won't exist.

Comment: There is also a chance someone implemented this and posted it at the [File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/).